# How to get the latest document of each group efficiently?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's take a collection named `values`, which contains the following documents.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "value1", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-06T15:20:13Z"), "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "value1", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-06T16:20:13Z"), "x" : 3, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "value1", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-06T17:20:13Z"), "x" : 3, "y" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "value2", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-06T16:20:13Z"), "x" : 10, "y" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "value2", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-06T17:20:13Z"), "x" : 20, "y" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "value2", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-06T18:20:13Z"), "x" : 10, "y" : 40 }
```

Here, if I group by `name`, then I should get the latest document (based on `date`) for each group. So, I should get the following documents.

```
{ "name" : "value1", "x" : 3, "y" : 4 }
{ "name" : "value2", "x" : 10, "y" : 40 }
```

I could do it by first sorting the documents in descending order based on `date` and use `$first` operator inside `$group` to get the documents. But, I think this might be inefficient due to sorting, as it would sort the whole collection to get the last value (I might be wrong).

Is there a better way to do it efficiently?

(Note: `date` does not have unique values)

Comment: Use the [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/index.html) aggregation operator within the `$group` to get your latest date for a grouping.

Comment: `$max` for the `date` field? Did you mean to do so in `$match`?

Comment: Yes `$max` applied on the date field. Something like this: `{ $group: { _id: "$name", date: { $max: "$date" } } }`, instead of sort and then apply $first in the group stage.

Comment: You cannot use `$max` operator, because it will check all fields to be greater than others... In your current sample `$max` could work, but it will return wrong results for many other names

Comment: @Valijon So `$max` will actually take the highest of all `date` regardless of `name`? If that's the case then we could not use it like that.

Comment: If you use `$max` for `date`, `x`, `y` fields, it will return the highest values individually. So if you have `{ "_id" : 7, "name" : "value2", "date" :  ISODate("2020-02-12T18:20:13Z"), "x" : 1, "y" : 0 }`, `$max` will return `{ "name" : "value2", "x" : 10, "y" : 40 }`

Comment: Yes, we can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I could do it by first sorting the documents in descending order based
>   on date and use $first operator inside $group to get the documents.
>   But, I think this might be inefficient due to sorting, as it would
>   sort the whole collection to get the last value (I might be wrong).

You can index on the `date` field - and the sort operation will be fast (or efficient), as it comes at the first stage of the pipeline.

*Optionally,* you can try this aggregation (gives the same output):

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$name", 
          max_date: { $max: "$date" }, 
          docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      } 
  }, 
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { 
          newRoot: { 
              $mergeObjects: [
                   { $arrayElemAt: [
                         { $filter: { input: "$docs", cond: { $eq: [ "$max_date", "$$this.date" ] } } },
                          0 
                    ] }, 
                    "$$ROOT"
              ]
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { _id: 0, docs: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

Comment: When you said "index on the `date` field", did you mean to make `date` an index or that sorting on `date` is fast?

Comment: You [create an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/index.html) on the date field which is used for sorting efficiently. Also see [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/index.html)

Comment: Also see: [$sort operator and performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html#sort-operator-and-performance).

Comment: The problem is that the `date` field is not unique, as you can see. But we could create an index on multiple fields so that the combination of `name` and `date` will be unique. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also, the problem with your proposed aggregation is that the `$push` in `$group` will store all the documents in it. So, if I had a million documents, under say `value1`, it would store all of it for the next stage in the pipeline. This would make it very inefficient.

Comment: Yes, you can create an index on the name+date _and_ sort on _both_ fields. Then do the group operation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215805/discussion-between-l-shane-john-paul-newton-and-prasad).